# Does org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors extension point support using TemplateCompletionProcessor with Generic Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried to extend Generic Editor using a simple completion processor that implements `IContentAssistProcessor` which provides keywords completion and it worked as expected.

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors"
    id="com.example.completion.completion.CompletionProcessor"
    name="com.example.completion.completion.CompletionProcessor">
    <contentAssistProcessor
        class="com.example.completion.completion.CompletionProcessor"
        contentType="com.example.completion.content-type">
    </contentAssistProcessor>
</extension>
```

Now I need to add template completions through `ABCTemplateCompletion` which extends base class `org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.TemplateCompletionProcessor` and should provide `alphabet` template after pressing `Ctrl` + `space`. Unfortunately It do not work with generic editor. But when I open the same file using a custom editor (`ABC Editor`) which uses the same `ABCTemplateCompletion`, I can use `alphabet` template. What is the problem with generic editor?

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.contentAssistProcessors"
    id="com.example.completion.completion.ABCTemplateCompletionProcessor"
    name="com.example.completion.completion.ABCTemplateCompletionProcessor">
    <contentAssistProcessor
        class="com.example.completion.completion.ABCTemplateCompletionProcessor"
        contentType="com.example.completion.content-type">
    </contentAssistProcessor>
</extension>
```

Complete Sample Project: https://files.fm/u/3pted4jv